# How to remove an object if all values in that object are 0

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object of objects like this

```
const data = {
   "CD": {
      "open": 0,
      "maxItemPrice": 0,
      "totalRevenue": 0
    },
   "DDA 1": {
      "price_category": "DDA 1",
      "items_for_sale": 24,
      "aggregate_holds": null,
      "aggregate_kills": null,
      "held": 35,
      "maxItemPrice": 37.5,
      "totalRevenue": 225,
      "open": 0,
      "sold": 11,
      "sellableCapacity": -11,
      "oversoldCount": 22
    },
   "DDA 2": {
      "price_category": "DDA 2",
      "items_for_sale": 48,
      "aggregate_holds": null,
      "aggregate_kills": null,
      "held": 80,
      "maxItemPrice": 33.33,
      "totalRevenue": 266.6400146484375,
      "sold": 16,
      "sellableCapacity": -32,
      "oversoldCount": 48,
      "open": 0
    },
   "DDA 3": {
      "items_for_sale": 0,
      "aggregate_holds": null,
      "aggregate_kills": null,
      "held": 0,
      "maxItemPrice": 0,
      "totalRevenue": 0,
      "sold": 0,
      "sellableCapacity": 0,
      "oversoldCount": 0,
      "open": 0
    },
}
```

and I want to remove all objects where all values are falsy, in this case `0` and `null`, so the final result will be something like this:

```
const data = {
   "DDA 1": {
      "price_category": "DDA 1",
      "items_for_sale": 24,
      "aggregate_holds": null,
      "aggregate_kills": null,
      "held": 35,
      "maxItemPrice": 37.5,
      "totalRevenue": 225,
      "open": 0,
      "sold": 11,
      "sellableCapacity": -11,
      "oversoldCount": 22
    },
   "DDA 2": {
      "price_category": "DDA 2",
      "items_for_sale": 48,
      "aggregate_holds": null,
      "aggregate_kills": null,
      "held": 80,
      "maxItemPrice": 33.33,
      "totalRevenue": 266.6400146484375,
      "sold": 16,
      "sellableCapacity": -32,
      "oversoldCount": 48,
      "open": 0
    }
};
```

I know how to remove concrete value from the object if it's falsy, I did it like this

```
let filteredObject = Object.fromEntries(
     Object.entries(data).filter(([_, v]) => {
        return v.open != 0 && v.open != null;
       })
     );
```

but I don't know how to remove the entire object if all values there are `0` or `null`.
How can I achieve this? Any example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just used a small modification to your code to enable it for all properties of the nested objects:

```
let filteredObject = Object.fromEntries(
     Object.entries(data).filter(([_, v]) => {
        return Object.values( v ).some( (el) => el );
       })
     );
```

`Object.values( v )` will return an array with all values from the nested objects. Using `.some()` we can check that at least one property has a truthy value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is exactly what I was looking for!